# Using divs on an image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code below for an image slider that stops when you hover on the image. I was wondering if there's anyway to do this but instead of using image tags using just use a div tag so I can create custom shapes to have on the slider with CSS. Can anyone point me in the right direction, when I try replacing the images with divs it stops working. Any thoughts?

```css
#scroller {
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  top: 14%;
}

#scroller .innerScrollArea {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#scroller ul {
  padding: 0;
  top: 10%;
  position: relative;
}

#scroller li {
  padding: 0;
  top: 7%;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.test {
width:100px;
height:200px;
background-color:pink;}
```

```html
  <!-- SCROLLING IMAGE GALLERY-->

  <div id="scroller" style="width: 536px; height: 263px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="innerScrollArea">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s511/Josh_Tilton/website/angels_landing_zpsn5dpgsui.jpg" width="536" height="263" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s511/Josh_Tilton/website/big_cottonwood_zpszx8qyyik.jpg" width="536" height="263" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- JS SCROLLING IMAGES CODE-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
        var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
        scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
        var curX = 0;
        scrollerContent.children().each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css('left', curX);
            curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
        });
        var fullW = curX / 2;
        var viewportW = scroller.width();

        // Scrolling speed management
        var controller = {curSpeed:0, fullSpeed:2};
        var $controller = $(controller);
        var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration)
        {
            if (duration === undefined)
                duration = 600;
            $controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed}, duration);
        };

        // Pause on hover
        scroller.hover(function(){
            tweenToNewSpeed(0);
        }, function(){
            tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
        });

        // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
        var doScroll = function()
        {
            var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
            var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
            if (newX > fullW*2 - viewportW)
                newX -= fullW;
            scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
        };
        setInterval(doScroll, 40);
        tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/bRMRWQ, It looks like working for me:)

Comment: Great code overall though. Mind if I keep this snippet and use it in my own projects?

Comment: I didn't create the code myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another `<li>` element with a `<div>` and some text in it and it halted just fine. There was no image in it at all.

[Check out the fiddle I created.](https://jsfiddle.net/difster/gg69cLpr/)

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use div tag, give class to your div tag and then insert image using css to that class.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the image like so.

In your Script:

```
  <ul>
    <li><div class='slidingIMG'><img src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s511/Josh_Tilton/website/angels_landing_zpsn5dpgsui.jpg" width="536" height="263" /><div></li>
    <li><div class='slidingIMG'><img src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s511/Josh_Tilton/website/big_cottonwood_zpszx8qyyik.jpg" width="536" height="263" /><div></li>
  </ul>
```

and in your Stylesheet. (The 10px is only to show an extremum to your current)

```
.slidingIMG img{

    height:10px;
}
```